# Does module.exports work differently in webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, require, commonjs

In this [tutorial](https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-understanding-webpack/) the author uses this code to exemplify exporting code:

// sum.js

```
var sum = function (a, b) {
    return a + b;
};
module.exports = sum;
```

But isn't this wrong? I thought the `module.exports` is an object and you're suppose to assign the key of `sum` to it and the `value` of the function to it similar to something like what this other [article](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/) did -

// greetings.js

// var exports = module.exports = {};

```
exports.sayHelloInEnglish = function() {
  return "HELLO";
};

exports.sayHelloInSpanish = function() {
  return "Hola";
};
```

. Did the first author mess up?

Answer (score 2):

`module.exports` is just a reference of what will be returned from `require()`. You can set its value to an `object` containing methods as well as you can just set it's value to a function or any other assignable value.

Comment: and it's scoped to a per file basis? so that the `module.exports` in each file is scoped to that file in the sense that setting its value to `'a'` in file a.js won't mess up setting its value to `'b'` in file b.js? Does commonjs just magically put all of these keys and values into 1 object for you to require from?

Comment: When using Webpack, all the files are bundled into one big file using IIFE modules. Which prevents variable names conflict between modules with the help of closure.

Comment: I'm still confused - is `module.exports` a global object or is it scoped to each file that uses it?